# Comparing template with actual data

Tags: angularjs

I have a template for a set of documents required. How do I compare template with the actual set of documents?

my template is v.template.docType and
my document is v. documents.docType ??

Using angularJs.

Comment: `v.template.docType === v.documents.docType`

Comment: That's the best I can do with what you little information you provided...